# The value 'null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Offset' because 'Offset' is not nullable

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-null-safety

I've been following a tutorial on youtube for flutter. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zv5T2C1oKus. I'm new to flutter and dart btw. I don't understand this error message.

> lib/main.dart:91:36: Error: The value 'null' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'Offset' because 'Offset' is not nullable.
>
> - 'Offset' is from 'dart:ui'.
>   points.add(null);
>   ^

here is my code

[image: error comes from "points.add(null)"]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the video you linked, there is a check whether `points[x]` is `null`, so I assume the elements of `points` should be nullable. You can achieve this with

```
List<Offset?> points = [];
```

(instead of `List<Offset> points = [];`).
The added questionmark makes it possible for elements of the list to be either a instance of the class `Offset` or the value `null`.

Comment: now this error comes

Comment: lib/main.dart:149:52: Error: A value of type 'Offset?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Offset' because 'Offset?' is nullable and 'Offset' isn't.
 - 'Offset' is from 'dart:ui'.
        canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, [points[x]], paint);
                                                   ^

Comment: You can make a value with a nullable type non-nullable as well. That is done using an exclamation mark: `canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, [points[x]!], paint);` You should only add the exclamation mark if you are sure `points[x]` can't be null.

Answer (score 0):

The points is non-nullable list.

So this time, it can be solved with to remove **points.add(null);** inside onPanEnd. (Or add non-null Offset.)

Comment: How do u do that? (add non-null Offset)

Comment: Sorry I'm new so forgive me for not knowing

Comment: For example, like Offset(0, 0); . I’m writing in smartphone so I'm sorry if the details are different.

Comment: Please try points.add(Offset(0.0, 0.0));

Comment: If you don’t want to add another offset, maybe you can solve this with only to remove points.add(null);.

Comment: both of those don't work

Comment: Points.add(Offset(0.0, 0.0)) just messes things up. because when I realease my finger it draws a line to the corner of the screen

Comment: removing the line of code just makes it so that my finger is hooked on and it draws lines everywhere I tap next